Optimizing Query to Retrieve Names from pg_buffercache View in PostgreSQL
I had a database with large amount of tables / partition tables where I need to retrieve the database name, relation name, parent relation name and tablespace name instead of their respective OIDs from pg_buffercache view. My current query involves joining pg_buffercache with pg_database, pg_class, pg_inherits and pg_tablespace to replace the OIDs with the relevant names. However, this query becomes extremely slow when dealing with a large number of tables.
Here is the query I am using:
SELECT 
    bufferid,
    pgc1.relname AS relation_name,
    pgc2.relname AS parent_relation_name,
    pgt.spcname AS tablespace_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN pgb.reldatabase = 0 THEN 'Shared system catalogs' 
        ELSE pgd.datname 
    END AS database_name,
    relforknumber,
    relblocknumber,
    isdirty,
    usagecount,
    pinning_backends
FROM 
    pg_buffercache AS pgb
LEFT JOIN 
    pg_class AS pgc1 
    ON pgb.reldatabase IN (0, (SELECT oid FROM pg_database WHERE datname = current_database()))
    AND pgb.relfilenode = pg_relation_filenode(pgc1.oid)
LEFT JOIN 
    pg_inherits AS pgi 
    ON pgc1.oid = pgi.inhrelid
LEFT JOIN 
    pg_class AS pgc2 
    ON pgi.inhparent = pgc2.oid
LEFT JOIN 
    pg_tablespace AS pgt 
    ON pgb.reltablespace = pgt.oid
LEFT JOIN 
    pg_database AS pgd 
    ON pgb.reldatabase = pgd.oid;

Here is the query plan generated with lot of Seq Scan
postgres=> explain analyze SELECT bufferid, pgc1.relname, pgc2.relname, pgt.spcname, CASE WHEN pgb.reldatabase = 0 THEN 'Shared system catalogs' ELSE pgd.datname END, relforknumber, relblocknumber, isdirty, usagecount, pinning_backends FROM pg_buffercache AS pgb LEFT JOIN pg_class AS pgc1 ON pgb.reldatabase IN (0, (SELECT oid FROM pg_database where datname = current_database())) AND pgb.relfilenode = pg_relation_filenode(pgc1.oid) LEFT JOIN pg_inherits AS pgi ON pgc1.oid = pgi.inhrelid LEFT JOIN pg_class AS pgc2 ON pgi.inhparent = pgc2.oid LEFT JOIN pg_tablespace AS pgt ON pgb.reltablespace = pgt.oid LEFT JOIN pg_database AS pgd ON pgb.reldatabase = pgd.oid;
                                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=197913.73..306625.37 rows=27197 width=277) (actual time=75543.679..202806.553 rows=66659578 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Seq Scan on pg_database  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.018..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (datname = current_database())
           Rows Removed by Filter: 3
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=197912.28..267521.16 rows=27197 width=221) (actual time=75543.666..149336.903 rows=66659578 loops=1)
         ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=197911.85..253672.28 rows=27197 width=221) (actual time=75543.637..96045.317 rows=66659578 loops=1)
               Merge Cond: (p.relfilenode = (pg_relation_filenode((pgc1.oid)::regclass)))
               Join Filter: (p.reldatabase = ANY (ARRAY['0'::oid, $0]))
               Rows Removed by Join Filter: 616
               ->  Sort  (cost=67.28..69.78 rows=1000 width=157) (actual time=74868.339..82287.389 rows=66659578 loops=1)
                     Sort Key: p.relfilenode
                     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1583216kB
                     ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=2.09..17.45 rows=1000 width=157) (actual time=17376.288..46385.909 rows=66659578 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (p.reldatabase = pgd.oid)
                           ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1.05..13.73 rows=1000 width=93) (actual time=17376.266..37425.982 rows=66659578 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: (p.reltablespace = pgt.oid)
                                 ->  Function Scan on pg_buffercache_pages p  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=33) (actual time=17376.226..25074.313 rows=66659578 loops=1)
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=1.02..1.02 rows=2 width=68) (actual time=0.023..0.024 rows=3 loops=1)
                                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                       ->  Seq Scan on pg_tablespace pgt  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=68) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=3 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=1.02..1.02 rows=2 width=68) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=4 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on pg_database pgd  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=68) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=4 loops=1)
               ->  Materialize  (cost=197844.57..200564.23 rows=543931 width=68) (actual time=675.255..893.286 rows=1001258 loops=1)
                     ->  Sort  (cost=197844.57..199204.40 rows=543931 width=68) (actual time=675.247..763.910 rows=490273 loops=1)
                           Sort Key: (pg_relation_filenode((pgc1.oid)::regclass))
                           Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 43176kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on pg_class pgc1  (cost=0.00..123714.31 rows=543931 width=68) (actual time=0.016..448.284 rows=539414 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using pg_inherits_relid_seqno_index on pg_inherits pgi  (cost=0.42..0.50 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=66659578)
               Index Cond: (inhrelid = pgc1.oid)
   ->  Index Scan using pg_class_oid_index on pg_class pgc2  (cost=0.42..1.44 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=66659578)
         Index Cond: (oid = pgi.inhparent)
 Planning Time: 1.101 ms
 Execution Time: 206171.454 ms
(35 rows)

How can I optimize this query to make it more efficient (in terms of execution time)? Are there any specific techniques or best practices to ensure the joins use the indexes already created on pg_class and other catalog tables effectively?

Yes enable_nestloop = off for the query.

That is making execution time even worse.
Planning Time: 0.865 ms
Execution Time: 308519.456 ms
(39 rows)

A good start would be to make work_mem much larger.  But how fast does this need to be?  This seems like the type of query which shouldn't need to get run very often.

@jjanes I am not sure about how fast I want, I just wanted to check what will be the most optimal way to write this query. Currently in explain plan I can see seq scan on catalg tables (pg_class) which is very large hence I was searching for a way to rewrite this query. And yes you are correct this is not used much often.

pg_class may be very large, but still reading and sorting it is a small fraction of the overall time.

With over 500GB of shared buffers, such a query can be expected to be quite slow.
An obvious problem with that query is that pg_buffercache_pages() always estimates a result row count of 1000, which might not give you the best plan.
You could create a wrapper function that has a better estimate:
CREATE FUNCTION my_buffercache() RETURNS TABLE (
   bufferid oid,
   relfilenode oid,
   reltablespace oid,
   reldatabase oid
)
   LANGUAGE sql
   COST 20000
   ROWS 67000000 AS
'SELECT bufferid,
       relfilenode,
       reltablespace,
       reldatabase
FROM pg_buffercache';

Perhaps using that function gives you a better plan.
